# Install Apache Ignite on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ignite

I am trying to install Apache Ignite on EC2 (CentOS).
Downloaded latest Ignite src (2.0) and installed Java 1.8 and MVN.

Next tried to run (inside Ignite folder) MVN setup but is failing:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:16 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.32.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1, /home/ec2-user/ignite/apache-ignite-2.0.0-src/parent/pom.xml, line 29, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.ignite:apache-ignite:2.0.0 (/home/ec2-user/ignite/apache-ignite-2.0.0-src/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:16 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.32.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ org.apache.ignite:ignite-parent:1, /home/ec2-user/ignite/apache-ignite-2.0.0-src/parent/pom.xml, line 29, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I am able to install same way on my Mac without this error. What could be a problem? Can MVN be set differently to avoid this error? Or is some issue with EC2/Apache Ignite compatibility? (I am not able to use AMI for Ignite since is not approved for usage within company network)

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with connection to maven repository, check if this repo accessible from your EC2 machine:

> Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.32.215] failed: Connection timed out

It's not necessary to build Ignite from src on your server, you can download binaries and use them.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have example (link for binaries) and step by step how to do it?

Comment: This seems to be link to binaries: https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries . Do you have experience building it from binaries? which procedure to follow? thanks.

Comment: Download binaries and run ignite.sh, as it described here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started#section-start-from-command-line

Comment: Downloaded (wget http://mirrors.koehn.com/apache//ignite/2.0.0/apache-ignite-2.0.0-src.zip), unzip binaries and tried but have error: 
bin/ignite.sh examples/config/example-cache.xml

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineRandomNumberGenerator
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.ignite.internal.util.portscanner.GridJmxPortFinder
bin/ignite.sh, WARN: Failed to resolve JMX host (JMX will be disabled): ip-x-x-x-x.x.x.com
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup

Comment: You downloaded source code again. For ignite-2.0 download http://mirrors.koehn.com/apache//ignite/2.0.0/apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin.zip

Comment: Thanks. Probably was half-sleep when was searching for it :) It looks like is working for a single node now. Was able to start Ignite (bin/ignite.sh examples/config/example-cache.xml) and can see:  "Topology snapshot Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=2, heap=1.0GB]".

Comment: That is now running on 1 EC2 node. I am able to start another Ignite on another EC2 instance. What is the way to connect 2 Ignite nodes on 2 separate EC2 instances in order to make a 'network' or a Apache Ignite 'grid' within the same AWS VPC? Thanks.

Comment: First of all you should configure DiscoverySpi https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.0/docs/cluster-config, so nodes will be able to see each other and second you need to configure CommunicationSpi:https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.0/docs/network-config. You can find configuration examples in apache ignite sources.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install ignite is :

1. download ZIP package from https://ignite.apache.org/
2. extract the content
3. run ignite_home/bin/ignite.sh